# Error in Export data from excel to sql server database

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, ms-office

I have try to copy data from excel sheet to sql server using sql bulk copy, but

I got error whenever try to open connection of excel sheet database I mean Microsoft ace oledb connection.

I have try "Enable 32-Bit Application = true" in Application Pool then It works fine, but I don't want to set it true.
How I can fix it??

I have share sample code in this ***excel_con.Open()*** comes error this point
    'Upload and save the file
            Dim excelPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath)

```
        Dim connString As String = String.Empty
        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

        Select Case extension
            Case ".xls"
                'Excel 97-03
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & excelPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                'Excel 07 or higher

                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excelPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
                Exit Select
        End Select

        Using excel_con As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            excel_con.Open()
            Dim sheet1 As String = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing).Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            Dim dtExcelData As New DataTable()
```

[This is the error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1T2y.jpg)

Comment: error is **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**

Comment: If you don't want to set `Enable 32-Bit Application` in IIS, since Microsoft ACE driver by default only runs in x86, try changing platform selection in `Configuration Manager` => `Active Platform` from "Any CPU" to "x86", or install [Office System Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734).